# how we can use only alphabet on the customer username in the magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account

How can i add validations for only alphabets in First name and Last name fields in Customer registration form?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Extend name.phtml file in your theme as below and add letters-only validation:-**

```
app\design\frontend\VendorName\themename\Magento_Customer\templates\widget\name.phtml
```

**First Name:-**

```
<input type="text" id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('firstname')) ?>"
               name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('firstname')) ?>"
               value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getObject()->getFirstname()) ?>"
               title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStoreLabel('firstname')) ?>"
               class="letters-only input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAttributeValidationClass('firstname')) ?>" <?php if ($block->getAttributeValidationClass('firstname') == 'required-entry') echo ' data-validate="{required:true}"' ?>>
```

**Last Name:-**

```
<input type="text" id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('lastname')) ?>"
               name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('lastname')) ?>"
               value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getObject()->getLastname()) ?>"
               title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStoreLabel('lastname')) ?>"
               class="letters-only input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAttributeValidationClass('lastname')) ?>" <?php if ($block->getAttributeValidationClass('lastname') == 'required-entry') echo ' data-validate="{required:true}"' ?>>
```

**Edited:**
I saw you want to try the validation for field, so you can achieve that by using schema in your module, to update the existing field in database

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Setup

```
namespace Demo\StreetLimit\Setup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
/**
 * @param EavSetup $eavSetupFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
) {
    $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
}

/**
 * Upgrades customer_eav_attribute table for validate_rules to set limit on character for Street address for DHL module issue
 *
 * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
 * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
 * @return void
 */
public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $setup->startSetup();
    /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $entityAttributes = [
        'customer_address' => [
            'street' => [
                'validate_rules' => '{"max_text_length":35,"min_text_length":2}'
            ],
        ],
    ];
    $this->upgradeAttributes($entityAttributes, $customerSetup);
    $setup->endSetup();
}

protected function upgradeAttributes(array $entityAttributes, \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup $customerSetup)
{
    foreach ($entityAttributes as $entityType => $attributes) {
        foreach ($attributes as $attributeCode => $attributeData) {
            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute($entityType, $attributeCode);
            foreach ($attributeData as $key => $value) {
                $attribute->setData($key, $value);
            }
            $attribute->save();
        }
    }
}
```

}

**This is just demo for street address field, you can same use this or name's that you want for first and last name**

**Now letters-only validation only accept letter in first name and last name, not numeric value.**

Comment: I will try it now. Thank you so much.

Comment: letters-only code is not working.
    
            <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('firstname')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('firstname')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getFirstname()) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->getStoreLabel('firstname')) ?>" maxlength="15" class="letters-only input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('firstname') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
        </div>
    </div>
 Please let me know if I am doing any mistake

Comment: please see my updated, answer, and accept the answer, as this is all requirements that you want, thanks Munesh

Comment: I do not have any module section in my code.

Comment: @Gurpreet if you want to set the limit on input field, then you should have to create the module, and do what i said, if you don't know how to create the module, then ill share the link reference that shows you to create the module.

Comment: Please share the link. How I can create a module because I am new to Magento. I do not know how to fix things. My client wants to limit the characters field. I did it but now he wants only characters in the first name and last name field. it is not working. I do not know that much about Magento. I am learning the magento.

Comment: ok, here is the link, https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/, no issue i'm open for any question, if you can accept the answer, it can helps others also, Thanks

Comment: Please Accept and up the vote for this Question Thank you:)

Comment: how I can  accept the answer?

Comment: Check now. I accepted the answer

Comment: I got the module section. Do I have to create a Setup new module? and put your give code inside.

Comment: yes you can put this on!

Comment: But I am afraid if it affects the live website. if something happened wrong?

Comment: just do local test first, after that go for live!

Comment: okay sure, I will try on the local.